# Compile result for native C++ code mixed with managed code for .Net import

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio

I am developing a c++ wrapper for my C# project.
I am a little bit confused about how the end result is compiled. So I have this situation:

A solution with one projects. This project is with Common Language RunTime Support (/clr). The native cpp Files are configured without Common Language RunTime Support (/clr) and NO precompiled headers.

So my questions are:

1. Why is it obligated that I have to use NO precompiled headers for the native cpp files?
2. What is the end result, is the native code compiled as machine code? Or is it JIT because I use the wrapper for .Net?

Native header:

```
    #pragma once

    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    class Person
    {
    private:
     string _name;

    public:
      Person(string name);
      ~Person();

      string GetName();
    };
```

Native cpp:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "Person.h"


    Person::Person(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }


    Person::~Person()
    {
    }

    string Person::GetName()
    {
       return _name;
    }
```

C++ wrapper header

```
#pragma once

#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

#pragma unmanaged
#include "Person.h" 

using namespace System;
using namespace msclr::interop;

namespace WrapperLib{

public ref class PersonManaged
{
private:
    Person *_person;
public:
    PersonManaged(String ^name){
        _person= new Person(marshal_as<std::string>(name));
    }
    ~PersonManaged()
    {
        delete _person;
        _person = 0;
    }

    String ^Getname(){
        return gcnew String(_person->GetName().c_str());
    }
};
}
```

Edit:

Thank you for the answer Luaan! This helped! I dowloaded ILSpy and opened the mixed assembly. I also found my native Person class in there.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[NativeCppClass, UnsafeValueType]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 24)]
internal struct Person
{
}
```

Now what is it like? There are the .Net usings like System an System.Runtime, but there is also the attribut for NativeCppClass?

Comment: Please leave a comment for down voting, so the next time I know what is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have precompiled headers - the problem is that managed precompiled headers are not compatible with native precompiled headers. From MSDN:

> Precompiled headers are supported under /clr. However, if you only compile some of your CPP files with /clr (compiling the rest as native) some changes will be required because precompiled headers generated with /clr are not compatible with those generated without /clr. This incompatibility is due to the fact that /clr generates and requires metadata. Modules compiled /clr can therefore not use precompiled headers that don't include metadata, and non /clr modules can't use precompiled header files that do contain meta data.

The [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173265.aspx) also describes how to get around this by forcing two different precompiled headers, one or .NET and one for native. This only makes sense for large projects, though.

As for the second question, it depends. The end result is either a native DLL, or a mixed managed/native assembly - in this case, I'd bet on the latter. I've only used C++/CLI for .NET wrappers of native types, though, so I might be wrong. It's very easy to check, though - just compile, and try using something like ILSpy on the resulting DLL - if it works, it's a .NET assembly, if it doesn't, it's a native DLL.

If that is indeed the case, then yes, the native code is simply machine code, while the managed parts are IL as usual. See [Mixed assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0w2664k.aspx) for further reference.